# TypeError: Cannot convert value dtype('<M8[ns]') to a TensorFlow DType

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow

No idea why I'm getting this error. I'm following [a Tensorflow tutorial](https://gist.github.com/martinwicke/6838c23abdc53e6bcda36ed9f40cff39) but changing the data source.

There are only two real variations. One is that I import two CSVs and `.merge` them:

```py
df = df_a.merge(df_b, how='left', on='race_id', sort=True)
```

the other is that i have to parse a column of times as follows:

```py
def parse_time(t):
    minutes, seconds, centiseconds = t.split('.')
    milliseconds = int(centiseconds) * 10 + int(seconds) * 1000 + int(minutes) * 60 * 1000
    return milliseconds

df_a['e'] = df_a['d'].map(parse_time).astype(np.int32)
```

Now a `df.dtypes` reveals:

```
a               object
b               float32
c               int32
d               object
e               int32
dtype: object
```

I've been careful to clean out all the NaN's. I'm not sure where to start with this error. Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: `dtype('<M8[ns]')` means `datetime64[ns]`, which is a numpy type. It seems tensorflow does not have support for dates, so you need to convert it to an `int64` first

Comment: Thats weird. There is a `datetime64` but its not getting fed to the `LinearRegressor`? So it must be trying to parse all the columns even though they are not all used?! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue.

In my case **the index of dataframe was replaced by a datetime column**. In my case I was building a neural network, and then this index wasn't import anymore, so fixed just resetting the index.

So, execute:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

And dropping the column(if you dit like me replacing the index):

```
df = df.drop('foo_date',1)
```